# ::after margin and padding

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a horizontal menu like this:

```
.leftNav li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
}
.leftNav li::after{
    content: " | ";
}
```

And I'm getting:

```
menu item 1 |      menu item 2 |      menu item 3 |
```

I'd like equal spacing between each:

```
menu item 1   |   menu item 2   |   menu item 3 |
```

I thought `margin` or `padding` would handle this, but it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the `::after` pseudo element is inside the `li` the `padding` will be applied after it and not either side of it. Try adding the `padding` to `.leftNav li::after` instead of the `li`.

```css
.leftNav li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline;
}
.leftNav li::after {
  content: " | ";
  padding: 1em;
}
.leftNav li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="leftNav">
  <li>menu item 1</li>
  <li>menu item 2</li>
  <li>menu item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. That occurred to me right after I posted the question.

Comment: No problem, probably one of those cases where you just needed to talk about it to lead yourself to the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

pseudo elements are considered part of the content of the parent element, so the padding is outside the content and the pipe. Try adding the padding to the `::after` pseudo element.

```
.leftNav li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
}
.leftNav li::after{
    content: " | ";
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the padding for `::after` element not for the list element.

```css
.leftNav li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline;
  color: #000;
}
.leftNav li::after {
  content: " | ";
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="leftNav">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```